# How to make buttons seen in group text messaging?

Tags: iphone, ios

Is there any standard way to re-create the buttons seen when group text messaging? (The buttons labeled John Nichols, Andrew Owens, etc)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get help from the below URL:

http://alexbarinov.github.com/UIBubbleTableView/

I've not had a chance to test it out, but this might be of interest to you for creating tokenizer uitextfiled:

http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/jstokenfield